# Referencing Django apps from subfolder

Tags: python, django

I'm referencing a Django app from a Python population script.

That's been working fine when the population script was put in the same folder as `my_project`, like below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Starting population script..."
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_project.settings')
    from persons.models import Person, Contact
    populate()
```

But now I'm trying to move my population script (which is not a Django app) to a subfolder called `population/`. Following errors are thrown when this is tried:

`ImportError: No module named persons.models`.

So I tried to change the import to an absolute import: `from my_project.persons.models import Person, Contact`.

That however yields `ImportError: No module named my_project.persons.models`.

I tried with a relative import as well, being `from .my_project.persons.models import Person, Contact`, but that yields `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Django 1.6 with Python 2.7 in a virtualenv under Windows.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything Django-specific here, it looks like you just don't have your `PYTHONPATH` set appropriately.

Comment: are you using virtualenv?

Comment: @Dorian: yes, I'm using virtualenv. Let me update the question as such.

Comment: Are you in your virtualenv when you launch the script? or in any case are you launching it with your virtualenv python interpreter or just the default one?

Comment: @Dorian: I can confirm I'm in the correct virtualenv when launching the script. Note: it used to work when the script was not in the populate/ subfolder (but was in the same folder as the Django apps).

Comment: try this: to append the app path to your PYTHONPATH before the import
               import sys
               sys.path.append("path_to_my_project")

Comment: Thanks @Dorian and @KevinChristopherHenry. Fixed by adding the path of the project (i.e. `../populate/`) to sys.path. I used `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))` in order not to hard code the directory. If you can convert your comments to an answer then I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

editing my answer with your edit, here is the solution:

```
 #append the app path to your PYTHONPATH before the import
 import sys
 import os

 sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
```